# Testing a nested custom hook with react-testing-library

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a hook in isolation with `@testing-library/render-hooks` in a React Native project. The hook I have looks something like this:

```js
const useStatus = () => {
  const [ status, setStatus ] = useState(null)
  const { data: data1 } = useDataHook1()
  const { data: data2 } = useDataHook2()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data1 && data2) {
      // Some logic to determine status based on data1 + data2
      setStatus(...)
    }
  }, [data1, data2])
  return { status }
}
```

So I want to test `useStatus` and I'd like to mock `useData1` and `useData2`, all three hooks of which are defined in the same file. My test looks like so:

```js
import * as hooks from 'path/to/hooks'

const data1Spy = jest.spyOn(hooks, 'useData1')
const data2Spy = jest.spyOn(hooks, 'useData2')

describe('useStatus', () => {
  it('should render', async () => {
    data1Spy.mockReturnValue({ data: 'foo' }
    data2Spy.mockReturnValue({ data: 'bar' }
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => hooks.useStatus())
    await waitForNextUpdate()
    console.log(result.current.status)
  }
}
```

The console logs values that I would expect if the nested data hooks weren't returning, and the error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

appears, which tells me that the mocks aren't being set correctly. (Thinking the SWR queries are trying to dispatch in a test environment, leading to unresolved promises floating around after the test finishes.)
Some things I've tried:

- Using `mockReturnValue` as seen in the above code
- Using `mockImplementation` instead of `mockReturnValue`
- Using `jest.mock` + `jest.requireActual` pattern as is done [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename)

I'm not sure what else to try. I've been able to mock hooks before using the above pattern when rendering a component, but this is my first time working with rendering the hook directly. Any thoughts?